# Shouldn't a long be big enough to be able to store a phone number?

Tags: java

When setting a mobile phone number variable using long or float it says 'Error: integer number to large: 07859664443'

Here's the code

```
public class StudentNode
{
    public long TelNumber;

    public void setTelNumber(long aTelNumber)
    {
        TelNumber = aTelNumber;
    }
}
```

Shouldn't a long be big enough to be able to store a phone number?

Comment: You should store phone numbers as Strings, not numeric values. There's no need to perform arithmetic on them.

Comment: Don't use numeric types to store a phone number.  Phone numbers aren't numeric (leading zeros are important).

Comment: That looks like an octal number to me. :) (That isn't someone's actual mobile, is it?)

Comment: Let's say my phone number is +18005551234P*111# ; how do you encode that in a long?

Comment: @skaffman Why is storing them as String better? Do they take up less memory or something?

Comment: @Elliot Brown: There are multiple characters allowed in a phone "number", not all of them digits. Look at your phone keypad, and tell me how you're storing the `*` character in a `long`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dtmf Also, in some countries, `0123456`, `00123456` and `123456` have *completely* different meanings.

Comment: Storing them as a String is better because while `long` can hold only digits -- with some restrictions, such as the maximum number of digits, and no leading zeroes -- but `String` can hold any number of digits, octothorpes, asterisks, etc, all of which may be necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Telephone numbers aren't numbers. They're strings. For instance, in the UK and many other European countries, the first digit of a full phone number is a 0. But a simple numeric type like `long` has no way to indicate that a leading 0 is significant, the number 07859 664 443 would be the value `7859664443`. The leading zero matters. Separately, it's not at all uncommon to see a number written like this: +44 (0)7859 664 443. Put that in your `long` and try to smoke it. :-)

Also, the formatting matters. 07859 664 443 is a lot easier to read and dial than 07859664443. In the U.S., they frequently put area codes in parentheses: (800) 123-4567, which again is easier for we poor humans to deal with than 8001234567.

In my experience, the best way to deal with phone numbers is to store them as strings, and largely to leave them the way they were entered, unless you want to limit the application to the phone numbers used in a very limited geographic area — and even then, things can change. Trying to build formatting rules into your application immediately introduces a maintenance item. When (when) the U.S. runs into the limits of its current (xxx) yyy-zzzz format, for example, a **huge** number of applications are going to need updates. Painful ones. Similarly, I used an application the other day that assumed all UK numbers were in the form (xxxxx) nnn nnn. This is no longer true, large metropolitan areas are now (xxx) nnnn nnnn whereas we more rural types are still on the old system. For a while at the beginning of the last decade, London's numbers were in the form (xxxx) nnn nnnn. You get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

The code you've shown us could not possibly have given the compile error mentioned in your subject. The real problem is that the integer literal starts with a 0, making it an octal (base 8) constant. Some of the digits (8 and 9s) aren't valid in octal literals.

As several other folks have already pointed out, phone "numbers" should be represented as `String`, not `long` or any other numeric type, so that you can avoid this problem and many others.

Comment: It's not a compile error it's when in bluej you click the method and try to add in a phone number.

Comment: If you were using a "real" compiler, you'd get a compile error; BlueJ is telling you about problems before the compiler even gets to see the code. That it does so by giving you a misleading message (the compiler message would, in fact, say that '8' and '9' aren't valid octal digits) is distressing; yet another example of BlueJ actually hampering rather than helping.